# what's wrong Error: Parse error on line 3: ...e6Djjb7OlVWLtVZc""main": "","alts" -----------------^ Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'STRING'

Tags: json

1. I'm trying to figure out what I need to remove/add to my code to fix it.
2. I'm getting an error with the token part of it so focus more on the token area so tokens through main is my issue.

Here's the error message I'm getting.

```
Error: Parse error on line 3:
...e6Djjb7OlVWLtVZc"        "main": "",     "alts"
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'STRING'
```

```
{
    "tokens": {
        "mfa.dRNvGxUk_sIJXB-YCsjuanxPLs1sA5vShO9LIu01P0O9TSjI4ZD-zPlQoOTAVEG5mx4He6Djjb7OlVWLtVZc"
        "main": "",
        "alts": [
            ""
        ]
},
    "status": {
        "main": "",
        "alts": "invisible"
    },
    "nitro": {
        "max": 2,
        "cooldown": 24,
        "main_sniper": true,
        "delay": true
    },
    "giveaway": {
        "enable": true,
        "delay": 15,
        "dm": "Hey, I won a giveaway !",
        "dm_delay": 25,
        "blacklist_words": [
            "bot",
            "test",
            "ban"
        ],
        "whitelist_words": [
            "nitro"
        ],
        "blacklist_servers": []
    },
    "invite": {
        "enable": true,
        "delay": {
            "min": 10,
            "max": 20
        },
        "max": 10,
        "cooldown": 6
    },
    "privnote": {
        "enable": false
    },
    "webhook": {
        "url": "",
        "good_only": false
    },
    "blacklist_servers": []
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the error message say what's wrong?

Comment: Hi ! Btw, what are we talking about ? ^^

Comment: i dont understand what i have to add the error message is confusing me PS.(New to coding) Error: Parse error on line 3:
...e6Djjb7OlVWLtVZc"  "main": "",  "alts"
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'STRING'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For your next question, please take the time to format code and similar text (such as JSON) with the `{ }` button. That way, line breaks and many other relevant elements are retained. The error message mentions line 3 and uses `----^` to pinpoint the error location. That's lost in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's invalid JSON. It starts with:

```
{
    "tokens": {
        "mfa.dRNvGxUk_sIJXB-...WLtVZc"
        "main": "",
```

The second opening curly brace starts a JSON object. Objects consist of key/value pairs. But the first entry (`"mfa..."`) is missing its key.

A correct JSON could look like so:

```
{
    "tokens": {
        "token": "mfa.dRNvGxUk_sIJXB-...WLtVZc",
        "main": "",
```

Comment: so what do i add

Comment: I've added a sample how a correct JSON could look. It adds a key and the comma at the end of the line. But the key (`"token"`) is just a guess as I don't know what's really expected.

Comment: thank you so much i fixed it